# R -- Method for Interpolation over 2d datset with missing values

Tags: r, 2d, interpolation

I am currently using the 'Akima' interp routine in order to do 2d linear interpolation.  I'm currently trying to do linear interpolations as best as I can by excluding the bad datpoints and interpolated values that depend upon them. I don't want to do any spline fitting just linear interpolation.

I can think of two ways to do this using the existing akima package;

1. by partitioning the 2d datasets into valid subsets that do not have missing data points, and then interpolating on each, and then merging the results.
2. or by setting the missing value to a nonsense value, (-1.0 in my case), and then marking the results where any interpolated value NA.  Unfortunately, the indices of the interpolation nodes do not appear to be returned, so I'll have to find these nodes myself in which case I should just write my own routine.

Each is a a bit of a pain and I'm sure there must be a better way or there must be a package to do one of the above as this I'm sure is a common problems that many have had.

Any recommendations for an alternative interpolation routine or method to use akima interp is greatly appreciated.
Bob

Comment: You complain about "pain". What about our pain in trying to answer a question with no workable example?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this is not yet a specific code issue.  It is a general methodology issue and a question related to recommendation for a general class of problems.

Comment: Have you checked Spatial Task View? Lots of 2D interpolation going on there...

Comment: I think a lot of interpolation routines assume that there are no NAs in the dataset (I know that gstat does). So I'm not sure if there is an out-of-the-box solution for you.

Comment: It's very likely that your note about "excluding bad datapoints" hides a multitude of potential disasters.  How can you even start to interpolate if you know there are bad values?  What are your criteria for a bad value in the first place? Typically one might first fit data to a function and then reject, say 3-sigma data. Like it or not, you won't get a useful response here unless you provide a sample and the result you want from it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the `Amelia` package?

Comment: Could you be a bit more complete in your answer? Please explain why the Amelia package is relevant.